# Circular heat maps in R?

Tags: r, heatmap, circlize

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059826/circular-heatmap-with-r-circlize-plot-area-and-row-labels) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887365/circular-heatmap-that-looks-like-a-donut), however, none of the other answers solve my problem.

Im trying to join together two (or more) separate heat maps and turn them into a circle. Im trying to achieve something like the image below (which I made by following the `circlize` package tutorial found [here](https://jokergoo.github.io/2020/05/21/make-circular-heatmaps/):

[image: circular heatmap]

In my data, I have multiple matrices, where each matrix represents a different year. I want to try and create a circular heat map (like the one in the image) where each section of the circular heatmap is a single year.

In my example below, I am just using 2 years (so 2 heat maps) but I cant seem to get it to work:

```
library(circlize)

# create matrix
mat1 <- matrix(runif(80), 10, 8)
mat2 <- matrix(runif(80), 10, 8)
rownames(mat1) <- rownames(mat2) <- paste0('a', 1:10)
colnames(mat1) <- colnames(mat2) <- paste0('b', 1:8)

# join together
matX <- cbind(mat1, mat2)

# set splits
split <- c(rep('a', 8), rep('b', 8))
split = factor(split, levels = unique(split))

# create circular heatmap
col_fun1 = colorRamp2(c(0, 0.5, 1), c("blue", "white", "red"))
circos.heatmap(matX, split = split, col = col_fun1,  rownames.side = "inside")
circos.clear()
```

The above code makes:

[image: circular heat mat attempt]

Im not sure where I am going wrong!? As when I use the `ComplexHeatmap` package, I am splitting the matrices correctly, as shown below:

```
#  using ComplexHeatmap package
library(ComplexHeatmap)
Heatmap(matX, column_split = split, show_row_dend = F, show_column_dend = F)
```

[image: split heatmap]

Any suggestions as to how I could achieve this?

Comment: The right command is `circos.heatmap(t(matX), split = split, col = col_fun1,  rownames.side = "inside")`

Comment: this seems to do the trick. Thanks